# using :memory: returns 'sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table:'

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, in-memory-database, in-memory

I am working on a messaging RESTful app using Flask on Python.
I need to implement an in memory solution but all the solutions I found online are not working.
Find the code below:

```
# Helper 
def _get_message(id=None):
    """Return a list of message objects (as dicts)"""
    with sqlite3.connect(':memory:') as conn:
        c = conn.cursor()
        if id:
            q = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id=? ORDER BY dt DESC"
            rows = c.execute(q, (id,))
        else:
            q = "SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY dt DESC"
            rows = c.execute(q)

        return [{'id': r[0], 'dt': r[1], 'message': r[2], 'sender': r[3]} for r in rows]

def _add_message(message, sender):
    with sqlite3.connect(':memory:') as conn:
        c = conn.cursor()
        id = str(uuid.uuid4().hex)
        q = "INSERT INTO messages VALUES (?, datetime('now'),?,?)"
        c.execute(q, (id, message, sender))
        conn.commit()
        return c.lastrowid
```

..and so on with other functions..
Then I am running the app and initialising the database (I've found this online not using an in-memory solution though). I'd like to take the form of my db_init.sql:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Test whether the database exists; if not, create it and create the table
    if not os.path.exists(:memory:):
        try:
            conn = sqlite3.connect(:memory:)

            # Absolute path needed for testing environment
            # sql_path = os.path.join(app.config['APP_ROOT'], 'db_init.sql')
            sql_path = os.path.join('db_init.sql')
            cmd = open(sql_path, 'r').read()
            c = conn.cursor()
            c.execute(cmd)
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
        except IOError:
            print("Couldn't initialize the database, exiting...")
            raise
        except sqlite3.OperationalError:
            print("Couldn't execute the SQL, exiting...")
            raise
    

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

db_init.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (
  id TEXT NOT NULL,
  dt TEXT NOT NULL,
  message TEXT NOT NULL,
  sender TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

But I get this error: 'sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table:'
I have also tried "file::memory:", "DataSource:memory:"  and ""file::memory:?cache=shared"", "file::memory:?cache=shared" uri=True

How can I use in memory with my initialised db_init.sql?

Comment: You have typo in first code block is `':memory'` should be `":memory:"` (note trailing `:`)

Comment: thanks, that was while I was typing the question actually

Comment: Doing `with sqlite3.connect(':memory:') as conn` creates a new database each time.  If you want to use an in-memory database you need to create the connection once, and make the connection available to your functions.